# Python/Django - Class cross referencing

Tags: python

Is it possible to have classes in Python cross reference each other in a class attribute?  For example:

```
class A(object):
    ref = B

class B(object):
    reverse = A
```

The specific use case is a Django model and it's serializer from Django Rest Framework.  Typically, you have to pass in a Django model instance to its serializer to instantiate the serializer, but I'd like to be able to get a serializer from the model instance, like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        default_serializer = MySerializer

    def get_default_serializer(self):
        return self.Meta.default_serializer(self)

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

# This is how you normally get a serializer:
MySerializer(MyModel.objects.get(id=1))

# But I want to do this, so I don't need to know what the default 
# serializer is in order to get one:
MyModel.objects.get(id=1).get_default_serializer()
```

I know that Django models allow you to use strings as foreign key arguments, then it lazy loads the related model.  Could I implement something similar here?

Comment: Why do you need to keep it in Meta? Can't you simply return the serializer in `get_default_serializer`? Cross class referencing seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I was trying to design this functionality as a mixin, so the mixin would define get_default_serializer, then use whatever is configured on the model.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But still you have to define `default_serializer` in a model. And since this method has only one line you really gain nothing except it gets more complicated and you have to deal with such problems. You could simply override this method in child class.

Comment: This is true.  Lets assume that I have enough functionality that I want to break it out into a mixin.  This could be YAGNI, but I'm interested to hear what the possible solutions are.

Comment: You also still run into a circular import problem unless you don't use only import and not from-import

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. You've never said that these classes are in seperate files.